# Compare a Spreadsheet cell value with a string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parseexcel

Hi I am trying to compare a cell value in the spreadhseet with a string as given below.

```
workbook = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.parse(name)

#Get the first worksheet
worksheet = workbook.worksheet(0)
puts worksheet.cell(4,0).to_s 
puts "SecurityKey".to_s
puts "SecurityKey".to_s.eql? worksheet.cell(4,0).to_s
```

I tried `==` , `.eq?` and all other possible string comparison techniques but it always results as false even when the two strings are the same. Can u help me out??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A cell object has numerous child objects and methods. The Value
> (read/write) method returns a Cell's value as it is stored internally.
> A cell's Text (read-only) method returns the value as it is currently
> displayed. For example, if cell has the value "1234.56789" formatted
> as Currency, the Value and Text methods return different values
>
> http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/04/automating-excel-with-ruby-rows-columns.html

Try using value or text

```
worksheet.Cells(4, 0).Value == "SecurityKey"
worksheet.Cells(4, 0).Text == "SecurityKey"
```

**Edit**

Avoid using parseexcel.  Try something like

```
require 'spreadsheet'

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
workbook = Spreadsheet.open '/path/to/file.xls'
first_sheet = workbook.worksheet 0 # or name
cell = first_sheet.row(1).at(4)
```

Comment: I tried the same but i get " undefined method `Text' for #<Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet::Cell:0x101176108> (NoMethodError)" when i try with worksheet.cell(x,y) and if i try with worksheet.Cells(x,y) or worksheet.Cell(x,y) it gets hanged up. Could you please help me???